# How to Run Shell Scripts on server using Browser

Tags: java, jsp, shell

I am having shell script whose output is output.zip.

i want to Run Shell script on server using browser and download output.zip.

Please suggest me how i can do this, which technology i should use.

Comment: you have java web app running on a server, and there is a zip file on that server, you don't want to download it via your java web-app, but via shellscript... can you give a reason, why not read the file in java and write response to client (browser)?

Comment: I think he wants to generate it using shell script and download it using web-app.

Comment: you are right @A4L I want to Run shell scripts from server and download output of the shell script

Comment: then have a look at @jakub.petr answer, you can alternatively provide download link to it after it is generated if you dont want to read it by yourself sream it to the client as jakub.petr suggests in his answer. Btw a better alternative to `Runtime.getRuntime(...).exec` is to use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your server platform but I assume you have JAVA there and you can handle http request.

Create output file with this command:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh test.sh");
```

The second part is to stream content of your file as response. Just set response header to

```
Content-Description: File Transfer 
Content-type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="YourFilename.zip"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Length: LengthOfYourFileInBytes
```

and you can send your file content as body of the response.